# ionic app ,on click of a button not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an app and this is second screen where i am getting problem.
There is a skip button and when i press it the "div containing text in it " should hide .

I have written codes in typescript file "home.ts" and have written html of it it in home.html and css in home.css

there are only 2 screens i have done with these codes,one is splash screen and other one is disclaimer or home screen where i am trying to hide the div with text on click of skip button

Here is home.ts code:

```
import { Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl:'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
@ViewChild('username')username;
@ViewChild('password')password;

  splash = true;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ) {
    }
    showhide(){

      var toggle = function() {
      var mydiv = document.getElementById('div');
      if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === ''){
        mydiv.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else{
        mydiv.style.display = 'block';
      }
      }
    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => this.splash = false, 4000);

  }  




    }



and here is home.html file

<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
            <script src="js/show.js"></script>
            <script src="build/animation.css"></script>
        </head>
             <body ng-controller="imageshow_hide">
                    <ion-content>
                            <div id="custom-overlay"[style.display]="splash ? 'flex': 'none'">
                                    <div class="flb">
                                            <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--top">
                                            </div>
                                            <img src="assets/logo.png">
                                            <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--bottom">
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="scroll-content">
                                                <img class="image1" src="assets/bg2.jpg"/>

                                                <div id="hides" class="image2"><img src="assets/whitetop.png"/>
                                                        <h2 style="text-align:center">WHY SHOULD I USE THIS APP

                                                        </h2>
                                                                <p>Our thoughts and everything we see feel hear taste and smell
                                                                shapes the unconscious mind.
                                                                By listening to affirmations daily.guided meditation and performing simple NLP techniques
                                                                you can re-program your mind to focus on the results you desire in life and develop
                                                                positive patterns for motivation and action
                                                                </p>

                                                </div>
                                                <div id="hides" class="image3"><img src="assets/whitebottom.png"/>
                                                    <h2 style="text-align:center">HOW TO USE THIS APP</h2>
                                                    <p>Don't listen to any of these recordings 
                                                        while operating machinery or driving.only listen to these materials if you
                                                        are in safe place where you can relax.
                                                        All contents provided within their applications are NOT meant to replace 
                                                        any qualified medical treatment or health related advice.
                                                        If you suffer from any mental disorder,NOT Listen to this material.
                                                        MindVolution accepts No responsibility or liability for any injury,loss or damage 
                                                        as direct or indirect result of the usage of the information here presented.
                                                    </p>

                                                </div>
                                                    <button (click)="showhide()" id="hides">
                                                    <img class="image4" ng-hide="checked" src="assets/skip.png"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                <img class="image5"src="assets/sound icon.png"/>
                                                <img class="image6"src="assets/sound icon.png"/>
                                </div>
                    </ion-content>
                </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am using this in my home.ts file

showhide(){

      var toggle = function() {
      var mydiv = document.getElementById('hidden');
      if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === ''){
        mydiv.style.display ='none';
      }
      else{
        mydiv.style.display ='block';
      }
      }
    }

Hidden is the id of two divs which i want to hide on click of button ( this button has an image inside it).this button has id =skipbtn


Here is html code of skip button where user will press to hide the tow divs containing image

<button click="showhide()" >
                                                    <img class="image4" id="skipbtn" ng-hide="checked" src="assets/skip.png"/>
                                                    </button>

Here are two divs which need to  be hide on click of skip button

<div class="scroll-content">
                                                <img class="image1" src="assets/bg2.jpg"/>

                                                <div id="hidden" class="image2"><img src="assets/whitetop.png"/>
                                                        <h2 style="text-align:center">WHY SHOULD I USE THIS APP

                                                        </h2>
                                                                    <p>Our thoughts and everything we see feel hear taste and smell
                                                                    shapes the unconscious mind.
                                                                    By listening to affirmations daily.guided meditation and performing simple NLP techniques
                                                                    you can re-program your mind to focus on the results you desire in life and develop
                                                                    positive patterns for motivation and action
                                                                </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="hidden" class="image3"><img src="assets/whitebottom.png"/>
                                                    <h2 style="text-align:center">HOW TO USE THIS APP</h2>
                                                    <p>Don't listen to any of these recordings 
                                                        while operating machinery or driving.only listen to these materials if you
                                                        are in safe place where you can relax.
                                                        All contents provided within their applications are NOT meant to replace 
                                                        any qualified medical treatment or health related advice.
                                                        If you suffer from any mental disorder,NOT Listen to this material.
                                                        MindVolution accepts No responsibility or liability for any injury,loss or damage 
                                                        as direct or indirect result of the usage of the information here presented.
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your question? If so you need to explain why it is an answer, if not, you should delete it and merge any necessary information into your question by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a div with id "div" and there isn't any in your html, did you intend to use id "hidden"? Then your code should be var `mydiv = document.getElementById('hidden')`.

A simpler way to achieve this is to create a boolean variable in your home.ts, e.g. isVisible, use *ngIf on the tags you want to depend on it's value to show or not, and then update it's value once the user clicks on the button.
e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible">Content to hide when user clicks the button</div>
<button (click)="isVisible = !isVisible;"></button>
```

To hide the splash screen is a good practice to use `this.platform.ready().then(()={this.splashScreen.hide();});`, by the way, you don't seem to be importing and using the splash screen native plugin, you are just giving a value to the variable splash.

Comment: I am using this in my home.ts file

showhide(){

      var toggle = function() {
      var mydiv = document.getElementById('hidden');
      if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === ''){
        mydiv.style.display ='none';
      }
      else{
        mydiv.style.display ='block';
      }
      }
    }

Comment: Hidden is the id of two divs which i want to hide on click of button ( this button has an image inside it).this button has id =skipbtn


Here is html code of skip button where user will press to hide the tow divs containing image

<button click="showhide()" >
                                                    <img class="image4" id="skipbtn" ng-hide="checked" src="assets/skip.png"/>
                                                    </button>

Comment: Here are two divs which need to  be hide on click of skip button

<div class="scroll-content">
                                                <img class="image1" src="assets/bg2.jpg"/>

                                                <div id="hidden" class="image2"><img src="assets/whitetop.png"/>
                                                        <h2 style="text-align:center">WHY SHOULD I USE THIS APP

                                                        </h2>

Comment: <div id="hidden" class="image3"><img src="assets/whitebottom.png"/>
                                                    <h2 style="text-align:center">HOW TO USE THIS APP</h2>
                                                    <p>Don't listen to any of these recordings

Comment: You shouldn't use the same id for different elements, the getElementById returns only one element, if you want to select multiple elements (in this case two divs) you should use a class and then use getElementsByClassName, this will return an array with all the elements it found, then you can iterate over it and change the display attribute.

Comment: I'm glad it's solved. If the answer above helped please mark it as an answer.